# Raycast issue with chase AI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my script, I have a patrol method and a chase method. My chase code using ray cast is not working properly. The only thing that works is my AI patrol code. When I hit a ray cast that I assign, it doesn't chase me. However, when I remove the patrol code in my script, my chase code works fine. What would be the problem? I want my AI to Patrol and Chase. If there is any collision and  if the player is outside of the collision, the AI will start to patrol again

```
public class LineTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

    private Transform targett;
    public Transform sightStart, sightEnd;
    public bool spotted = false;
    public GameObject arrow;
    public GameObject target;
    public bool facingRight = false;

    public float speed = 8;

    [SerializeField]
    float moveSpeed = 3f;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Vector3 localScale;
    float dirX;
    Vector3 directionToTarget;

    void Start()
    {
        localScale = transform.localScale;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        dirX = -1f;
        target = GameObject.Find ("Girl");

    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (transform.position.x < 1f)
            dirX = 1f;
        else if (transform.position.x > 20f)
            dirX = -1f;


        Raycasting ();
        Behaviours ();
    }

    void Raycasting ()
    {
        Debug.DrawLine (sightStart.position, sightEnd.position);
        spotted = Physics2D.Linecast (sightStart.position, sightEnd.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer ("Girl"));
    }

    void Behaviours()
    {
        if (spotted == true) {
            arrow.SetActive (true);
            directionToTarget = (target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2 (directionToTarget.x * moveSpeed, directionToTarget.y * moveSpeed);
        } 
        else 
        {
            arrow.SetActive (false);
        }

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 (dirX * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        CheckWhereToFace ();
    }

    void CheckWhereToFace()
    {
        if (dirX > 0)
            facingRight = false;
        else if (dirX < 0)
            facingRight = true;

        if (((facingRight) && (localScale.x < 0)) || ((!facingRight) && (localScale.x > 0)))
            localScale.x *= -1;

        transform.localScale = localScale;
    } 

}
```

Comment: You could try putting `Raycasting()` into an `if(!spotted)` statement. If the code works then, you at least know that the linecasting works properly

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a if(!spotted) in your FixedUpdate